# Method 'Finalise' in type 'Glass.Mapper.Sc.IoC.DependencyResolver' ... does not have an implementation

Tags: glass-mapper, upgrade

We were on 8.2.3 and I am trying to get our instance up to 9.3. I started with a vanilla 9.3 initial install and installed an update to apply our custom renderings, templates, etc. At the end of the installation I got the error below:

> Method 'Finalise' in type 'Glass.Mapper.Sc.IoC.DependencyResolver' from assembly 'Glass.Mapper.Sc, Version=4.3.4.197, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
>
> Description: An
> unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
> request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
> error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Finalise' in type
> 'Glass.Mapper.Sc.IoC.DependencyResolver' from assembly
> 'Glass.Mapper.Sc, Version=4.3.4.197, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
> current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [TypeLoadException: Method 'Finalise' in type
> 'Glass.Mapper.Sc.IoC.DependencyResolver' from assembly
> 'Glass.Mapper.Sc, Version=4.3.4.197, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.]
> Dkg.Web.App_Start.GlassMapperScCustom.CreateResolver() +0
> Dkg.Web.App_Start.GlassMapperSc.Start() +11    (Object , Object ) +9
> Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
> Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
> PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
> +236    Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
> Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +220
> Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +1145
> System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
> appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +580
> System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
> MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +165
> System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
> appContext, HttpContext context) +267
> System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
> appContext) +341
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Method 'Finalise' in type
> 'Glass.Mapper.Sc.IoC.DependencyResolver' from assembly
> 'Glass.Mapper.Sc, Version=4.3.4.197, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.]
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +523
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
> +107    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
> wr, HttpContext context) +688

Comment: Check if you have maybe double `.config` files for Glass Mapper. If you had already some configs in your project and then you installed Glass from nuget, it will add its config again and you may see exceptions like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know about 3 reasons that could be the issue:

- Check if you have maybe double `.config` files for Glass Mapper. If you had already some configs in your project and then you installed Glass from nuget, it will add its config again and you may see exceptions like that.
- You have old versions of Glass mapper dll files in your `bin` folder. Check all of them if they are correct (especially look at `Glass.Mapper.dll`).
- Some of your projects still reference old `Glass.Mapper.Sc.Core` nuget package instead of new `Glass.Mapper.Sc.93.Core`. Use "Manage nuget packages for your solution`option and find`Glass.Mapper.Sc.Core` in installed packages.

Comment: 1. I found 2 configus which mention Glass, but they don't seem to be to be in conflict: Glass.Mapper.Sc.config and Glass.Mapper.Sc.start.config.  *******
2. I'm not sure how to check versions of the dlls, can you provide guidance?  *******
3. I have the most recent of Glass on the project but should I have both "Glass.Mapper.Sc" and "Glass.Mapper.Sc.Core"? I have both installed (always has been).

Comment: In older Sitecore version there was `Glass.Mapper.Sc.Core` nuget package. Now it should be `Glass.Mapper.Sc.93.Core` with *.93.* (or other Sitecore version) in its name. Make sure you don't include the nuget package without the number

Comment: Upgrading to the glass mapper version you told me seems to have resolved this problem. A new error has occurred, but I'll start a new post on that error if I can't figure it out. Thank you for your help. Marking this as the answer.

Comment: Removing all GlassMapper references and re-adding them solved the issue.